# Not able to connect from Windows 11 to VMWare Linux VM

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine, vmware, vmware-workstation

I am using windows 11 ( Host OS).

I have VMWare Workstation Pro where Ubuntu VM was created.

In that Ubuntu VM, there is web application which is running on port 19000.

**Inside VM(Ubuntu), the below URL is working from browser or curl command.**

http://localhost:19000/ping

**Inside Host(Windows 11) , the below URL not is working from browser or curl command.**

http://localhost:19000/ping

Should I configure on windows 11 or VMWare Workstation?

Comment: `http://localhost:19000/ping` would refer to the host not the VM

Answer (score 0):

`localhost` refers to the current computer.
The host and the VM are two different computers, so `localhost` in the host
is the host, while `localhost` in the VM is the VM (and not the host).

Use in the Ubuntu VM the command `ifconfig` to find out its
IP address.
You may then use this IP in the host with a URL like
`http://IP:19000/ping`.

Note this this further depends on the setting you have used for the
Network adapter of the VM.

Comment: Now network adapter is configured to NAT. I tried using above, it is not working.

Comment: What are the IP addresses of the host and VM?